# Trigger a python script in power BI on a button click (input data for the python script is inside the power bi and the output should be loaded back)

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, azure-pipeline-python-script-task

So I have a PowerBI requirement , I will try to break my question into steps for simplicity

I have a dataframe in power BI and it has two columns A and B,
Now I have a python script which runs on A and B and gives back column C and D.

Now my question is, is there a way I could do it on call (button click), this seems so possible but couldn't get there.

(I tested it manually by edit query -> transform -> run python scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Python steps in Power Query run only on refresh, and refreshes are only supported in Power BI Desktop or when using a personal gateway.

Python *visuals* in a report run any time the page renders, but only generate a visual output.  They don't change data in your data model.

Comment: Is there any way that I could do it with the combination of power apps and power BI? Just wondering if there is route to do that?

Comment: A power app could call a web API.